# What crafting recipes are these?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods

Something went wrong with my Crash Landing modpack and the recipes seem to be mixed up.
(There's no crash log since it actually opens fine)

**Question: Can you identify what is the correct item that the following recipes make, and what mod is it from?**
*Note that the outcomes in the pictures are wrong. ie. A Iron Pickaxe requires Iron Ingots and sticks, NOT a stick and coal (that's torches).*

[image: Shouldn't it be a bottle and a dirt block?]
[image: That should be a bottle and two salts.]

Comment: I believe those are hammers, possibly from the statues mod? (Can't remember the name). Have you tried making them?

Comment: @Ben it's not **Ex-Nihilo Hammers**. These are the recipes: http://i.imgur.com/EjWv4SO.png (taken from the MC forums page) and it only needs two sticks, not three.

Comment: I would backup your world and redownload the modpack.

Comment: @ZekeSonxx But that wouldn't be answering the question would it? And I actually am playing a modified version of the Crash Landing Modpack. *(The one where you add your own mods)*. The reason it's doing this is because the IDs is hard-coded into the mod. So, I have to swap the mod item's ID with the ID for the water bottles.

Comment: if the IDs are hardcoded then the mod dev is a inconsiderate moron, tell him to allow them to be defined in the config

Comment: Is anyone going to answer the question instead of debating about whether to answer it or not? (Or either: There are item ID conflicts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following recipes are for **Sledge Hammers** (They're actually called a "[Material] Sledge") from the **Artifice** Mod.
It is available in the following materials: Wood, Stone, Iron, Gold and Diamond.

[image: Correct output item: A Stone Sledge]

Item Wiki Page: http://wiki.technicpack.net/Stone_Sledge_(Artifice)